# Add params to existing ActionResult object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method `GenerateLinks()` which takes an `ActionResult` object named `result`.  In that method I want to generate links using a modified version of `result` that will include an additional id param for each `id`.  Note that `HtmlHelper.ActionLink()` requires an `ActionResult`.

```
// Client-side
@Html.GenerateLinks(Mvc.Areas.MyArea.Index(), Model.ids);

// Server-side
MvcHtmlString GenerateLinks(this HtmlHelper helper, ActionResult result, List<string> ids)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        // How to add id to result where result becomes Mvc.Areas.MyArea.Index(id)?
        sb.Append(helper.ActionLink(id, result-with-id-as-param);
        sb.Append("<br/>");
    }
    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

Even though I know there are alternative ways to generate these links besides using `ActionLink`, my ultimate question is: **Is it possible to add `id` as a param to an existing `ActionResult` object?  If so, how?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
foreach (var id in ids)
{
    // How to add id to result where result becomes Mvc.Areas.MyArea.Index(id)?

    // *** ANSWER
    result.GetRouteValueDictionary()["id"] = id;
    // *** ANSWER

    sb.Append(helper.ActionLink(id, result);
    sb.Append("<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your actionresult

```
public ActionResult Index(id = defaultvalue){
    //AR code here
}
```

and then you pass the Id if needed. you also set a `defaultvalue` for id in case nothing is passed through.

Comment: My controller code already handles the default condition.  My question is: how can I modify the object `result` to go from `Mvc.Areas.MyArea.Index()` to `Mvc.Areas.MyArea.Index(id)` if that's possible?

Comment: yes, just pass the id through. as long as you can pass that actionresult from view to controller, it should work. `Mvc.Areas.MyArea.Index(id)`

Comment: Thanks, I actually found the answer: use `GetRouteValueDictionary.Add()` as follows: `result.GetRouteValueDictionary().Add("id", id);`  I will post a clearer answer after the 8-hour window elapses.